# TI Nspire: Return a list in a function

Tags: lua, ti-nspire

I have a function that acts upon the pixeldata of an image for the sake of simplicity, th eimage has only one row which means that I can use lists to hold the data.

So said function needs to return this list but just doing

```
...
Return (SomeFormulaThatResultsInAList)
...
```

results in a "Incorrect type"-error.

My assumption is that `Return`can only return numbers, not lists, am I right? If so, how can I return a list?

Btw, I am using a TI-Nspire CX CAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My assumption is that `Return` can only return numbers, not lists, am I right?

That is correct. From the TI Nspire reference guide:

> `Return` *[Expr]*
>
> Returns *Expr* as the result of the function. …

In the language of the TI manual, an *Expr* must be a algebraic expression. It doesn't need to be a number -- along the lines of `2x+5` is fine -- but it has to be something "shaped like" a number. A list isn't suitable.e

There is no way to directly return a list from a function in the TI CAS environment. It's simply not a feature which the language supports.

What you could do as a workaround, however, is rewrite the function as a program (`Prgm`), and store the result to a global variable with a predetermined name. It's ugly, but it'll work.

Comment: Why can't we simply use Matlab in exams... But thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: I used the predecessor to the Nspire (the TI-92) during high school. I've forgotten a lot about it, but this quirk stuck in my memory.

Comment: ok, I finally resolved the issue. I actually misunderstood the operation I had to implement and it doesn't even return a List but a number. The actual problem was a typo in a variable name that caused the variable name to be interpreted as a string instead of the variable value. Now that I fixed the typo, everything works :)